# Struct variable doesn't work in main function in c

Tags: c, struct

I'm trying to get a struct variable from another file in c. But when I do define a variable inside of other file and trying to printing this variable in main file it didn't work.

***Main File***

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tesst.h"

int main()
{
   struct tst t;
   this_test(t);
   printf("%s", t.string);

   return 0;
}
```

***Other File Header***

```c
#ifndef _TESST_H
#define _TESST_H

struct tst
{
   char *string;
};

void this_test(struct tst t);

#endif
```

***Other File***

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "tesst.h"

void this_test(struct tst t)
{
   t.string = "this is test";
}
```

When I tried to execute this program it print nothing. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have invoked undefined behaviour since you are trying to print the value of an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: You are passing the struct by value, so edits don't propagate back out. Read up on parameters passed via value, by reference, by pointer.

Comment: You never call `this_test`, and even if you did, that function only modifies a copy of its argument.

Comment: If I use strcpy function for initializing a struct variable then its work? But I this strcpy is not safe because I remember strcpy function in banned list from git. Do you know any alternative function?

Comment: "strcpy function is banned list from git"?  What does that mean, and how is it relevant?   But you don't need strcpy or strlcpy, you just need to initialized your variable.  If you want to use the function defined in the other TU for initialization, you need to call it.  If you want to use a variable defined in the other TU, you should use it instead of the local variable.  (Note that your "Other file" does *not* define any variables, but just manipulates local variables in a function that is never called.)

Comment: You need to pass as the structure as a pointer to modify by value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure passed as a parameter to the function is only a copy. To modify the structure of the main function in the this_test function, you must pass its address. It's like the scanf function where you have to pass the address of the variables you want to modify.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct tst
{
   char *string;
};

void this_test(struct tst *t)
{
   t->string = "this is test";
}

int main()
{
   struct tst t;

   this_test(&t);
   printf("%s", t.string);

   return 0;
}
```